# create button with variable link

Tags: button, web

I have an text file on my ftp server that contains a link. And I would like that a button on my website get the link and directs me to this. I'm new to this, so it would be nice if you could give me some hints.
Thank You a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/YOUR_FILE" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

YOUR_FILE = filename including path. (ex. documents/document.docx)

Comment: And does this directs my to the link in the text file or to the file on the ftp server?

Comment: file on ftp server. If your ftp server has permission to access it.

Comment: But I would like to direct to the link in the file.

Comment: No way, you can't do that except that file isn't .html. ;)

Comment: No problem. Sorry.